# What is the purpose of values-w820dp?

Tags: android

When I create a new project in Android, values-w820dp folder will always be created. I would like to know more about why this folder exist and why this folder only contain dimens.xml file. What is main the purpose of this folder? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

values-w820dp is basically the Folder to find values for devices that are at least 820 device independent pixels wide.
So, for any dimension settings you want to do for such devices, you will go to this file -/res/values-820dp /dimens.xml: and define appropriate dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

as Google said for sw600dp :  [Use the Smallest-width Qualifier](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

One of the difficulties developers had in pre-3.2 Android devices was the "large" screen size bin, which encompasses the Dell Streak, the original Galaxy Tab, and 7" tablets in general. However, many applications may want to show different layouts for different devices in this category (such as for 5" and 7" devices), even though they are all considered to be "large" screens. That's why Android introduced the "Smallest-width" qualifier (amongst others) in Android 3.2.

The Smallest-width qualifier allows you to target screens that have a certain minimum width given in dp. For example, the typical 7" tablet has a minimum width of 600 dp, so if you want your UI to have two panes on those screens (but a single list on smaller screens), you can use the same two layouts from the previous section for single and two-pane layouts, but instead of the large size qualifier, use sw600dp to indicate the two-pane layout is for screens on which the smallest-width is 600 dp: